# Is there a word for "when there is no story to a series". Where every episode's/movie's story is independent

Tags: single-word-requests

What if I want to convey to someone that you can watch this series from any episode; The series is not in continuation, everything is independent. [Black Mirror](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2085059/) is an example for this.

Is there a word for this?

Comment: I would disagree that this is a duplicate question. This question asks about a series with completely independent episodes (different characters, plot etc) where the previous question talks about episodes within a linked series (ie, same characters, possibly a series arc) which can stand alone. But I have no idea how to get a topic unflagged, so good luck: maybe repost the question noting that it is not a duplicate and indicating why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A series with each episode forming an individual plot would be **episodic**.

episodic

```
1 Containing or consisting of a series of separate parts or events.
‘an episodic narrative’

1.1 Occurring occasionally and at irregular intervals.
‘volcanic activity is highly episodic in nature’

2 (of a programme or story) broadcast or published as a series of instalments. 
‘episodic television is a difficult medium to write for’
```

{[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/episodic)}

Comment: That is indeed one sense in which 'episodic' is used. To improve your answer, please add a reference to this usage from a dictionary say, preferably adding a caveat that 'episodic' is also used more generally for 'presented in instalments'. // Please now point to the relevant sense, and flag the distractor/s.

Comment: Heh seems we both edited it simultaneously, does that caveat also apply to TV shows? I can't remember ever seeing it being used in that context when discussing series.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard 'episodic' outside behavioural analysis/ medical registers. Note that 'episode' and 'episodic' probably have very different register biases. Consider 'telescope' (n) and 'telescope' (v).

Comment: I disagree with *episodic*. Any broadcast that is broken into segments is *episodic*. For example, Dr. Who is episodic and every episode carries on from the previous.

Answer (score 3):

This is called an ***[anthology series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_series)***

I'd quibble with Wikipedia's definition

> An anthology series is a radio or television series that presents a different story and a different set of characters in each episode or season/series

slightly, in that an anthology series could have recurring characters. *Star Trek:TOS* was such an anthology.

There is a danger with recurring characters, in that the writers of such series often let those characters' backstories and personal problems develop into a continuity between episodes, sometimes degenerating into a full-blown soap opera. This happened to *Star Trek: TNG* and the later series.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of wikipedia.  I would go as far as to say that I think Sherlock Holmes is an anthology too.

Comment: @NibblyPig Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Often *standalone* is used to describe an episode that has no connection to a previous or next episode.

Although the dictionary definition can be I.T. related depending on which dictionary you consult, the word is often used outside of its field.

[Standalone in Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/standalone)

> standalone software or a standalone computer works on its own without
>   being part of a set, or without being connected to other computers

I would say:

> The episodes in *Star Trek* are pretty standalone, compared with *Babylon
>   5*.

Comment: "Odyssey," might do for unrelated although it has a connotation of travel as well. I am voting up "'Standalone," as I think NibblyPig got it right.